# Prevent the back action after logout in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I am try to prevent back button after logout in WordPress. When I log out from admin panel redirect me to login page then when I click on back button page load admin panel cached (if click on elements in cached page redirect to login page because session expired).
How can I Prevent the back action after logout in WordPress?

WordPress have any function for prevent cache page?

I must use JavaScript?

Notes: My web server is NGINX

Comment: Is it possible that this is theme specific or part of a custom modification?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is something I use and seems to work on many different browsers.

Go to your wp-includes/functions.php file and add this code at the very bottom (you may need to clear your wordpress cache one time so it shows on the pages.

```
function custom_admin_js_force_logout() {
        echo '"
<script>
    window.onunload = function(){};
    if (window.performance && window.performance.navigation.type === window.performance.navigation.TYPE_BACK_FORWARD) {
        document.body.innerHTML=null; // hide page before reload
        location.reload();
    }
</script>
    "';
}
add_action('admin_footer', 'custom_admin_js_force_logout');
```

Comment: Thanks. This work on admin page or every page even user not logedin?

Comment: Works only on admin pages if someone uses back button and not logged in. If someone is logged in it does not effect them, only refreshes page when back button is used.